# Open sets definition

Tags: real-analysis

I find it really confusing to understand the open set definition which goes:

> $N$ is an open set in $E$ if for each $x\in N$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B(x, \varepsilon)$ is contained in $N$

Could someone please try to break it down for me or maybe a graph.

It would all help

Comment: I recommend to use the definition to proof some set such as (0,1) is open but [0,1] is not?

Comment: @LiChunMin how can i proof with the definition?

Comment: Actually you can also prove "open ball is open" by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go a bit into the intuition in 2D. In the end I will explain how this connects back to 1D, because I assume $E$ is the real number line.

---

See the two pictures below. It is common to picture (at least in visual applications) the open sets with a dashed boundary, to indicate that these points (the boundary) does not belong to the set itself. So the left set should be closed, the right one should be open.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Because on the left, the boundary belongs to the set, you can choose $x$ on this boundary. Now ask yourself: is there a little circle (ball) around $x$ that is completely inside the set $N$? No of course not. At the boundary, moving only a little bit in the wrong direction will bring you outside.

In contrast, for the right image, the boundary does not belong to $N$. Thus it is not possible for you to choose $x$ on the boundary. But when $x$ is not on the boundary, it can wiggle a bit inside of $N$ without leaving it. Maybe just a tiny tiny bit. But this bit is sufficient to choose a circle $B(x,\varepsilon)$ around $x$ that is completeley contained in $N$. And this is what is so special about open sets. In *any* point you are *sufficiently inside* the set, so that you can wiggle without leaving.

On the left side, there are still point where you can wiggle without falling out of $N$, but the important thing for open sets is that this is true *everywhere*. And on the left side we found the boundary where this is not true.

---

In the 1D-case of $E$, you cannot imagine this balls as circles or balls, but you have to choose the appropriate 1D-analogon: intervals. Also, going with the anagoly of "wiggling a bit", you now can only wiggle in two directions: forth and back, and not up and down or whatever.

Sitting in $N=[0,1]$ at the point $x=1$, only moving a *tiny tiny* bit in direction of $2$ will bring you outside $N$. So $1$ is a boundary point of $N$ and $N$ is not open.

But when you are in $N=(0,1)$, you cannot sit in $1$ (or $0$), because these points do not belong to $N$. Instead, you will be at some point close to $1$ (or to $0$), say $1-\varepsilon$. At this points, you can wiggle in all direction by a bit of $\frac12\varepsilon$ without leaving $(0,1)$. Hence, the 1D-analogon of the ball $$B\left(x,\frac\varepsilon 2\right)=\left(x-\frac\varepsilon 2,x+\frac\varepsilon 2\right)$$ is completely inside $(0,1)$. This is true for all $x$ you can choose. Hence $(0,1)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

It means that around every point $x\in N$ you can find (read: draw if it makes it easier to understand, but this definition can be used in settings where drawing is not easy) a ball of positive radius $\varepsilon$ such that all points within the ball (that is all points near $x$) are within $N$. I.e. no point in $N$ is on the boundary. The whole point about $E$ is just that when considering openness in $E$ you should only consider points in $E$,

Comment: That was really helpful good bless you

Comment: Specifically, the whole point about $E$ can be illustrated like this: $(0,1]$ is open in $[-1,1]$ (but not in $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you asked. Pick any $x \in (0,1)$. $0>x>1$. Take $\epsilon = \min\{x, 1-x\}$. You can check that the open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ is contained in $(0,1)$.